# dimensions in batch normalization

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I'm trying to build a generalized batch normalization function in **Tensorflow**.

I learn batch normalization in this [article](http://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html) that i found very kind.

I have a problem with the dimensions of the **scale** and **beta** variables: In my case batch normalization is applied to each activations of each convolutional layer, thus if i have as **output of the convolutional layer** a tersor with size:

```
[57,57,96]
```

i need that **scale** and **beta** have same dimension as the convolutional layer output, correct?

here's my function, the program works but i don't know if is correct

```
def batch_normalization_layer(batch):
   # Calculate batch mean and variance
    batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(batch, axes=[0, 1, 2])

    # Apply the initial batch normalizing transform
    scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([batch.get_shape()[1],batch.get_shape()[2],batch.get_shape()[3]]))
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch.get_shape()[1],batch.get_shape()[2],batch.get_shape()[3]]))

    normalized_batch = tf.nn.batch_normalization(batch, batch_mean, batch_var, beta, scale, 0.0001)

    return normalized_batch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the documentation of `tf.nn.batch_normalization`:

> mean, variance, offset and scale are all expected to be of one of two
>   shapes:
>
> In all generality, they can have the same number of dimensions as the
>   input x, with identical sizes as x for the dimensions that are not
>   normalized over (the 'depth' dimension(s)), and dimension 1 for the
>   others which are being normalized over. mean and variance in this case
>   would typically be the outputs of tf.nn.moments(..., keep_dims=True)
>   during training, or running averages thereof during inference.
>
> In the
>   common case where the 'depth' dimension is the last dimension in the
>   input tensor x, they may be one dimensional tensors of the same size
>   as the 'depth' dimension. This is the case for example for the common
>   [batch, depth] layout of fully-connected layers, and [batch, height,
>   width, depth] for convolutions. mean and variance in this case would
>   typically be the outputs of tf.nn.moments(..., keep_dims=False) during
>   training, or running averages thereof during inference.

With your values (scale=1.0 and offset=0) you can also just provide the value `None`.